# Exercise 11.1.G Vakil FOAG

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes, flatness, dimension-theory-algebra

I am trying to solve Ex 11.1.G from Ravi Vakil's FOAG. It says if $X$ is an affine scheme over $k$, a field and $K|_k$ is an algebraic field extension, then $X$ is of pure dimension $n$ iff $X_K:=X\times_k K$ is of pure dimension $n$.

Here's my attempt at a solution. Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$. Then $X_K=\operatorname{Spec}(A\otimes_k K)$. The canonical map $X_K \rightarrow X$, in this case corresponds to the homomorphism of $k$-algebras namely $A\rightarrow A\otimes_k K$; $a\mapsto a\otimes 1$

Since $K|_k$ is an integral extension, so is $A\otimes_k K|_A$. Thus the Going-Up theorem holds true.

Also since $K$ is a free $k$-module, $A\otimes_k K$ is a free $A$-module and faithfully flat. Since $A\hookrightarrow A\otimes_k K$ is a flat ring extension, the Going-Down theorem holds true.

Now say $P$ be a minimal prime ideal of $A\otimes_k K$. Then $p:=P \cap A$ is a minimal prime ideal of $A$ by Going-Down theorem. Conversely if $p$ is a minimal prime of $A$ and $P$ lies over $p$ (since it is an integral extension) then $P$ is a minimal prime ideal of $A\otimes _k K$ by Incomparability.

Assume $X$ is of pure dimension $n$. Then for any minimal prime $p$ of $A$, we have $\operatorname{coht}p=\dim X$. If $P$ is a minimal prime of $A\otimes _k K$, then  $\operatorname{coht} P =\operatorname{coht} P\cap A=\dim X $ by Going-Up Theorem and Incomparability. Thus $X_K$ is of pure dimension $n$ as well.

Now assume $X_K$ is of pure dimension $n$. Then if $p$ is a minimal prime ideal of $A$, then $p=P\cap A$ where $P$ is a minimal prime of $A\otimes_k K$. Again by Going-Up and Incomparability, we get $\dim X_K=\operatorname{coht}P=\operatorname{coht} P\cap A $. Thus $X$ is of pure dimension $n$.

I hope this is a correct solution. I am pretty sure there exists alternative solution along the lines of Vakil's hints or preferably without using flatness since Vakil does not develop it upto this point but I simply can't get it. To be more precise, Vakil has first asked to reduce the problem to $A$ being an integral domain. I am stuck with this part without using the Going-Down theorem for flat ring extensions. Any help/insight/suggestion will be most welcome.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what exactly your question is - are you asking about whether your proof is right, how to do the problem via Vakil's hints, or both? In the case that you're asking about the hints, it would probably be helpful for you to copy those in to your post so that answerers don't have to go look them up elsewhere.

Comment: I am just stuck with the part where Vakil has asked to reduce it to the case of an integral domain. For that part, I am crucially using Going-Down Theorem for flat ring extensions. My primary question is how to avoid using this theorem. I included my solution to show how I am using the Going-Down Theorem.

Comment: Is $X$ of finite type over $k$? If so, consider using Noether’s normalization lemma.

Comment: Alas, no such condition is given.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for the reduction?  If $Q\subset A':=A\otimes_k K$ is a minimal prime, then $PA'\subset Q$ for some minimal prime $P\subset A.$  Thus it suffices to check that $A'/PA'$ is pure of dimension $n$. But $$A'/PA' = (A\otimes_k K)\otimes_A (A/P)= (A\otimes_A A/P)\otimes_k K = A/P\otimes_k K   $$ So we've reduced to $A/P\subset A/P\otimes_k K$, as desired.

The only thing that seems slightly sketchy is the second equality in the centered line...

Edit: If you downvote, please let me know what's wrong with the argument, as I am interested in the correct reduction.

Comment: This looks fine. As for the step you consider sketchy $$(A\otimes_k K)\otimes_A A/P\cong A/P \otimes_A (A\otimes_k K)\cong (A\otimes_A A/P)\otimes _k K\cong A/P\otimes_k K$$